# Yowsup number validation missing config.json

Tags: yowsup

Fresh installation, yowsup 3.2.3 with all prereq and depnds. on CentOS7 
Everything was just fine(i thought), successfully received confirmation code from WA, but with en error: 
TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'config'
So, on validation  
(yowsup-cli registration --register XXXXXX  --phone XXX --cc X --mcc XXX --mnc XX --debug
)
i receive error: 
ValueError ("config.id is not set.") (Couldnt find a config for profile XXX) 
Also it appears that config.json wasn't even generated automatically. 
Only axolotl.db exists in profile directory.

Any thoughts and ideas how to fix this appreciated.
Thank you.

**debug log on registration**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/yowsup-cli", line 4, in 
**import**('pkg_resources').run_script('yowsup2==3.2.3', 'yowsup-cli')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 651, in run_script
self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", 
line 1448, in run_script
exec(code, namespace, namespace)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yowsup2-3.2.3-py3.6.egg/EGG-
INFO/scripts/yowsup-cli", line 679, in 
if not parser.process():
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yowsup2-3.2.3-py3.6.egg/EGG-
INFO/scripts/yowsup-cli", line 350, in process
self.handleRequestCode(self.args["requestcode"], config)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yowsup2-3.2.3-py3.6.egg/EGG-
INFO/scripts/yowsup-cli", line 369, in handleRequestCode
self._config_manager.save(self._config)
TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'config'